# Prevent multiple connexion to my web application

Tags: javascript, connection, browser

I would like to prevent multiple connexion to my web enterprise application in the same browser (window or tab) for a user.

How can i do that using Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a session variable (a date and time) and store it in localStorage. Check it on window.load, and if it exists then close the window, or prevent loading further.

**Edit:**

I created a complete solution, maybe I'll find some use for it in the future:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var interval = 10000; //can be modified to be faster, now it's 10 seconds
            // localStorage is available everywhere
            // sessionStorage is available only in current page / tab, 
            // so we can allow page refresh
            if (localStorage.getItem("catch") && !sessionStorage.getItem("catch")) {
                var date = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("catch"), 10));
                if (Date.now() - date < interval) {
                    //prevent further loading, hide things etc.
                    document.write('catch');
                }
            } else {
                setInterval(function () {
                    var date = Date.now();
                    localStorage.setItem("catch", date);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("catch", date);
                }, interval);
            }
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine a solution with cookies or localStorage:

1. On page load:

   - Check if `X` exists either as a cookie or localStorage. If it exists, show an error and redirect to an error page.
   - If `X` is not present, proceed.
2. On page onload (`window.unload` and `window.onbeforeunload` events) remove `X`.

Comment: I have do that using a cookie but when the browser crash (dont go to window.unload) the cookie is not deleted ..

Comment: That's why I said to store a datetime, if it is not recent, it means window.unload didn't run in the past, but you can still let them in.

Comment: Rudy, could you explain step by step your solution please ?

Comment: @wawanopoulos I have edited my answer and added the code with the complete solution.